# Eigenvalues of $AB$ and $BA$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ and $B$ be $m \times n$ and $n \times m$ real matrices.

I proved that if $\lambda$ is a nonzero eigenvalue of the $m \times m$ matrix $AB$ then it is also an eigenvalue of the $n \times n$ matrix $BA$. But I am having trouble finding an example showing that this need not be true if $\lambda=0$

Thank you in advance

Comment: Think of it this way: You need to prove that $AB$ may be invertible while $BA$ is not. What is the maximal possible rank of $AB$ or $BA$?

Comment: respectively m and n

Comment: AB and BA have same eigen values if order are same

Comment: I don't see how to relate with the example $\lambda=0$

Comment: The largest possible rank for either $A$ or $B$ is the *minimum* of $m$ and $n$. So that must be the case for either product too. (Do you see why?)

Comment: Yes but I need an example

Comment: Try looking for one when $n=1$ and $m=2$.

Comment: $A=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$, $B=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @PavelJiranek What can be said about the rank and the order of AB ?

Comment: @user43418 Well, $AB\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$, $\mathrm{rank}(AB)=\mathrm{rank}(BA)=1$ and both $AB$ and $BA$ have the same nonzero part of the spectrum (just $\{1\}$ in this case). It's just a special case of the Vedran's example.

Answer (score 1):

Just take any nonzero (column) vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and, for $n = 1$, define

$$A := v \in \mathbb{R}^m \equiv \mathbb{R}^{m \times 1}, \quad B := v^T \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times m}.$$

Note that $v^Tv = |v|^2 \ne 0$, so $BA$ is an invertible matrix of order $1$. What can you say about the rank and order of $AB$?

An explanation, following the question in the comments:

> First, $AB$ is of order $2$. But,
>
> $$\operatorname{rank}AB \le \min\{ \operatorname{rank}A, \operatorname{rank}B \}.$$
>
> Since $A$ and $B$ have one column/row (respectively), their rank is at most $1$, so $AB$ also has rank at most $1$. Since $AB \ne 0$, its rank is exactly $1$, although that part is not important.
>
> So, $AB$ is a square matrix of order strictly bigger than the rank ($2 > 1$), i.e., it is not of a full rank. What is this telling you?

However, my intention was that you take some $v$ -- **any** $v$ you want! -- that is a nonzero vector. For example, try

$$v = e_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

and see what you get with $A$ and $B$ defined as above.

Comment: I am not sure but I know that AB gives us one element

Comment: Can you clarify ?

Comment: @user43418 I've just edited my answer. Feel free to ask if something remained unclear.